# I am a beginner and want to try the loop because I failed to try it in java

Tags: java, while-loop, case

I tried add the loop in my switch case, in the IDE there is no problem code, but when it runs why does it always appear "java: reach end of file when parsing" wrong where is my loop?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * @author AZ
 **/

public class Karyawan {
    
    public Karyawan() {
    }
    
    public void hitungGaji(){
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int menu, hari;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(input.hasNextInt()){

        System.out.println("Kalkulasi Gaji");
        System.out.println("1. Staff");
        System.out.println("2. Manager");
        System.out.println("3. Direktur");
        System.out.println("Pilihan Menu : ");
        menu = input.nextInt();


            switch (menu){
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Masukan Hari : ");
                    hari = input.nextInt();

                    Karyawan staff = new Staff(30, hari);
                    staff.hitungGaji();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Masukan Hari : ");
                    hari = input.nextInt();

                    Karyawan manager = new Manager(50, 10, hari);
                    manager.hitungGaji();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Masukan Hari : ");
                    hari = input.nextInt();

                    Karyawan direktur = new Direktur(75, 20, 300, hari);
                    direktur.hitungGaji();
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Pilih menu yang sesuai");

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need at least one more closing brace. This should be visible in your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You are not terminating class definition with `}`.
Simply add one more line at the end of the file with `}` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a closing brace '}' for the main class. Unmatched opening and closing braces are the main reason for "reached the end of the file while parsing" error messages!